# What is the best way to recharge an iPod Touch battery?

Tags: ipod-touch, battery

I wonder how to handle the recharging of my iPod touch ? I've heard that there are some actions to have to be done regularly or actions that arms the battery (like memory effect etc...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you’re looking for the info straight from [Apple’s iPod Battery’s Page.](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipods.html), which contains all the information that you need to keep your battery as healthy as possible.

In any case, as with any other modern battery, avoid excessive heat not only when recharging but also when the device is not in use.