# How can I make my first generation iPad's battery last longer?

Tags: ipad, battery

What are some of the things I can do to make my iPad (Wi-Fi) battery last a long time once it is charged?

I have the first generation iPad and run iOS 3.

Comment: Clarification Needed: When you say to make the battery "last a long time", do you mean that you want to maximize the duration of usable time for a given charge cycle, or that you want to increase the overall longevity of the battery's usable lifetime?

Comment: I mean for the charge to last a long time

Comment: In that case, the other posters have the right idea. Reduce the amount of work the battery is being asked to do. Running the backlight as dim as you can stand is probably the biggest thing, and manually use the sleep/wake switch to turn of the iPad when you're not using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't need to connect to a network turn off WiFi.  You will also want to go into the Settings:

- turn down the brightness (Brightness & Wallpaper)
- turn off Bluetooth (General)
- turn off "Push" and set mail to fetch manually (Mail, Contact, Calendars) / (Fetch New Data)
- turn off sounds (General)
- turn off location services (General)
- Turn off Notifications
- and check any apps to see if any poll wifi (if you keep it on)

For additional help, I wrote up an article here with pictures:
http://www.squidoo.com/prolong-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-battery

In the end, it really depends on how you use your iPad.  Good luck!--

Comment: I suggest re-ordering in rough order of effects. Brightness probably belongs at the top of the list.

Comment: Good idea, mankoff.  I've reordered the best I can, but if anyone has any suggestions let me know.  I've also added a link that has the list with pictures.

Comment: I'd be surprised if turning off sounds makes any difference, but the others all make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, your iPad’s battery life will eventually last longer if you follow the [Apple’s Advice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/what-is-the-best-way-to-recharge-an-ipod-touch-battery/1195#1195), specially regarding battery’s temperature.

Answer (score 3):

Turn down screen brightness, don't play games, turn off bluetooth. Standard battery life increasing tips.

How much longer do you need it? I understand that the battery life (even with WiFi) is fairly decent on the iPad.

Answer (score 3):

Killing apps manually will not affect battery life without effecting user experience.

Apps that stay active in the background typically do so for a limited time because they have a specific task that needs completing (like completing a download, or sending a mail message.)

iOS manages background processing aggressively in order to ensure that no extra battery is used unnecessarily.

Answer (score -1):

If you're running the beta of iOS 4.2, killing multitasking apps can also impact battery life.

Comment: Killing apps does not increase battery life, you are misinformed. @richarddas goes into some more specific details too in another answer here.