# How can I maximise the life of my iPad battery?

Tags: ipad, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to recharge an iPod Touch battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/what-is-the-best-way-to-recharge-an-ipod-touch-battery)

Since the iPad battery cannot be replaced, how can I make sure that it lasts as long as possible, preferably years? E.g. should I always keep it charged, or always let the battery run to 0% before recharging?

Note: not the same as [How can I make my iPad's battery last longer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/how-can-i-make-my-ipads-battery-last-longer) which is about battery life *during use*.

Update: this question looks very much like: [What is the best way to recharge an iPod Touch battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/what-is-the-best-way-to-recharge-an-ipod-touch-battery) *(sorry, only found after posting this)*. This is slightly more general but perhaps is a duplicate?

Comment: The thing is, it will probably be the same answer. And the best one will be the one [from Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipad.html)

Comment: Are you sure that "iPad battery cannot be replaced". Maybe we can not do it ourself, but the Apple Repair Center will, isn'it ?

Comment: @LoïcWolff The link you provided is the best answer to this question. Can you possibly move it from a comment to an actual answer? (I didn't want to slide in and write one up as you clearly got to this first.) I think the following is more than enough to answer the question (from Apple's article) *"For proper reporting of the battery’s state of charge, be sure to go through at least one charge cycle per month (charging the battery to 100% and then completely running it down)."* There's really nothing else to add on top of that (everything else being snakeoil).

Comment: Yes, you're all correct. The battery can be replaced ([by Apple](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipad.html)). And this is probably a duplicate. If so, please close and accept my apologies... :)

Comment: @cksum done. Even though it's kind of a duplicate, people searching for "iPad" will more likely find it on Google.

Comment: @Philip - if you must close this, please re-read the question because you've chosen the wrong "duplicate".

Comment: Changed the duplicate link. Sorry I missed that. If it still isn't correct, just @me with the proper link. Cheers

Comment: @PhilipRegan, no problem, thanks. I suggest you *don't* close it based on the other comments here. But it's up to you - you're the expert! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipad.html):

> ### Use Your iPad Regularly
>
> For proper reporting of the battery’s state of charge, be sure to go through at least one charge cycle per month (charging the battery to 100% and then completely running it down).